# Printing a PDF consisting of pages of different sizes

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have combined several PDF documents into one using Adobe Acrobat. Some of the original files are 11 x 7 and I cannot get them to print, so the whole document shows up on 8½ x 11, and the borders are cut off. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! Can you tell us something about the print settings you tried? Please feel free to edit your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `pdfjam` which is in most GNU/Linux package managers.  I include an example for the full project work which uses `pdftk` for completeness, which is also ubiquitous.

Firstly, let's assume we are in a directory with .pdf files to put together, and that alphanumeric order is acceptable for us.  (If not, things listed first have lower page numbers, and the command takes any number of fields that are pdf files until the `cat` field):

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output varying-size-sum.pdf
```

(There are ways to use pdftk to rotate pages automatically as well, which is why I mention it.  Ask in comments please if needed.)

So let's make these all into US Letter now, with a pdfjam tool:

```
pdfjoin varying-size-sum.pdf --paper letterpaper --fitpaper false --outfile letter-size-sum.pdf
```

I grabbed most this quickly from http://writeup.org/resize-pdf-a4-letter since I always forget command syntax.  While the example's interest differs from yours, the syntax looks applicable to your case.